# Find row and columns of matrix index in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, indexing

I want to ask something, is there any way to get the row number and column number if I know the index number of a matrix? For example, I have A= 3x3 matrix, and I want to find the row and column for index number 5 on the matrix. The answer should be like this: rows=2 columns=2.

Thank you! Please help me out. I've been stuck on this for a while now. :(

Comment: You should always include attempted solutions, an explanation of how the results differed from the desired results, any error messages you received, and examples (sample data, in this case) to give people a frame of reference for what you're asking. Please read this [advice on how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Be sure to follow the link at the bottom to Jon Skeet's blog post [Writing the perfect question](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx). Pay special attention to the "Golden Rule".

Comment: I'm sorry.. Will read and follow the rules thoroughly next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps try `ind2sub`?

```
IND = [3 4 5 6]
s = [3,3];
[I,J] = ind2sub(s,IND)

I =
     3     1     2     3

J =
     1     2     2     2
```

[Via](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ind2sub.html)